# Where can I find the indicative yield of soon-to-be-issued Treasury bonds on Charles Schwab?

Tags: bonds, yield, treasury, schwab, auction

In Vanguard, one may see the indicative yield of soon-to-be-issued Treasury bonds on https://personal.vanguard.com/us/FixedIncomeTrading:

[image]

Where can I find the indicative yield for soon-to-be-issued Treasury bonds on Charles Schwab? I could only find the Evaluated Price so far, which makes it inconvenient to compare soon-to-be-issued Treasury bonds of different maturities:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried asking Schwab support?

Comment: @keshlam contacted by chat: "That is a great question Franck. For this question I will need to refer you to speak with the fixed income/bonds team. Our Fixed Income department is here Monday - Friday: 8:30 am - 6:00 pm eastern time and their direct number is 800-626-4600."

Answer (score 2):

You can find the indicative yield of soon-to-be-issued Treasury bonds on Charles Schwab's website under the "Bonds & Fixed Income" section. Here's how:

Go to the Charles Schwab website ([www.schwab.com](http://www.schwab.com)).
Hover over the "Investing" tab in the top menu and select "Bonds & Fixed Income" from the dropdown menu.
On the "Bonds & Fixed Income" page, scroll down to the "New Issues" section.
In the "New Issues" section, you can see a list of upcoming Treasury bond offerings, including their maturity dates and indicative yields.
Note that indicative yields are estimates and may change as market conditions change or the bonds are actually issued. It's important to carefully review the prospectus and other information before investing in any bond offering.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I don't have any "Investing" tab in the top menu (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcBtz.png). I can find a list of upcoming Treasury bond offerings on https://client.schwab.com/Areas/Trade/FixedIncomeSearch/FISearch.aspx/TreasuryAuctions but there's no indicative yields: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRHso.png Can you please add a link or a screenshot? Thanks!